# Paste: combine rows for each row, up to only the number of rows in the smallest row-ct file

Tags: bash, paste

Suppose I have two files,

```
// foo
a
b
c
d

// bar
x,y,z
p,d,q
```

The problem is:

```
paste -d ',' foo bar

... 

a,x,y,z
b,p,d,q
c
d
```

Instead, I would like to (somehow) produce the following:

```
a,x,y,z
b,p,d,q
```

However, currently, the only way to do this that I see is to write a mini-program that checks the line count of the smallest file, and runs paste on the truncated files.

Worst case scenario, I have to write a compiled home cooked tool to keep the command line "easy" for purposes of rapid scripting and agility.

There must be some way I can do this with the already existing tools, but I don't see how.  Is there a way to do this conservative paste operation?

My current best solution is:

```
paste -d ',' foo bar | awk -F ',' '{if(NF > 2){print $0}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR == NR {T[NR] = $0; next} {$0 = T[FNR] OFS $0} NF == 4' OFS=, file[12]
a,x,y,z
b,p,d,q
```

Comment: this is a specific solution.  I appreciate it, but it is not a solution for the question, which calls for a generic paste operation that pastes only lines which have matching counterparts in the other files.